# place two layouts besides each other

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

My layout look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ightwall"
    android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#6CEB87"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="my list"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#D5D4D4">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/mylist"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/createlist_mylist"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxHeight="100dp"
            android:maxWidth="100dp"/>

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/freeadd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/createlist_freetext"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/categoryadd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/createlist_categorysearch"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxHeight="100dp"
            android:maxWidth="100dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/favproductadd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/createlist_favproduct"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxHeight="100dp"
            android:maxWidth="100dp"/>



    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want the two linear layers to look like this:

[the red layout will be for buttons ,and the green layout will be for changeable screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0b8T7.png)

I'm developing in android studio .
I need the red layout to fill a fixed width the the green layout to fill the rest of the screen.

[i want to get rid of the empty space i marked in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydRnd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `android:weightSum="1"`  in main layout and give  `android:layout_weight` (`layout_width should be 0dp when you set layout_weight`) to other two layouts

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight=".7" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#6CEB87"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="my list" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="4"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:background="#D5D4D4"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mylist"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:maxHeight="100dp"
                android:maxWidth="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/freeadd"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:maxHeight="100dp"
                android:maxWidth="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/categoryadd"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:maxHeight="100dp"
                android:maxWidth="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/favproductadd"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:maxHeight="100dp"
                android:maxWidth="100dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it works thanks but if i need the red layout to wrap its content? what i need to change?

i need it to be the size of the buttons inside it

Comment: means ? explain via image

Comment: use match_parent instead of wrap_content in button

Comment: can i make the layout match the content?

Comment: saw me image  .. you want control of red layout full width ?

Comment: in TextView use 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:text="my list" />

Comment: i want the layout to wrap the image views- i added a picture above

Comment: means you dont want empty space below 4 images?

Comment: i don't want empty space in the right side of the 4 images

Comment: is u r 4 images are static ?

Comment: See updated code android:weightSum="4" in LinearLayout and android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" in ImageView

Comment: still where you get problem ?

Comment: i wanted to make the layout with the images to wrap its content, but instead i just moved the images to the center ,so it looks a bit better

Answer (score 0):

Add the `android:layout_weight="1"` to the second `LinearLayout`, and set the width to 0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ightwall"
    android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        ...

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp" // change
        android:layout_weight="1" // add layout_weight
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#D5D4D4">

        ...

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```